# Php regex redirect

Tags: php, regex

I need help with a regex redirect.

I have a working regex

```
'^page\.php\?t=(\d+)$' => 'page/t-$1/'
```

to redirect

```
/page.php?t=123 > /page/t-123/
```

I need regex to redirect

```
/page.php?t=123/dynamic-text-123/ > /page/t-123/dynamic-text-123/
```

Comment: Maybe [`^page\.php\?t=(\d+)\$u=\/(?:\w+-)+\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/oB4tAw/1)

Comment: Try `^page\.php\?t=(.*)$`

Comment: This worked, Thank you   '^page\.php\?t=(.*)$' => 'page/t-$1/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You effectively only need to remove the `.php?t=` portion.

Since it seems that you are comfortable hardcoding the leading `page` component, you only need to match the trailing `t` value with a lazy wildcard (`.*?`) and exclude the optional trailing `/` then append that captured value to `page/t-`, then apend a slash at the end like so:

```
 '^page\.php\?t=(.*?)/?$' => 'page/t-$1/'
```

I am making the trailing `/` match optional, since it is not always there yet it seems you want the `/` in the replacement no matter what.

Comment: I have a question just for my understanding. Why make the ending forward slash optional  `/?` when the greedy `.*` already matches it?

Comment: Because in the first sample input there is no `/` at the end, but in the second sample input, it is present at the end.  The desired replacement always wants the `/` at the end, so I am hardcoding it into the replacement and omitting it from the capture group.

Comment: Wouldn't the optional `/` at the end be in the [captured group](https://regex101.com/r/OSrgRT/1) with the greedy `.*`?

Comment: My mistake, I should have tested.